# Lamda count total records by category and subcategory

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I have two entity

**Category**

```
public class Category
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public int? ParentId {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public virtual ICollection<Document> Documents {get; set;}
}
```

**Document**

```
    public class Document
    {
      public int Id {get; set;}
      public int CategoryId {get; set;}
      public string Name {get; set;}
      public virtual Category Category {get; set;}
    }
```

How I can get total documents by categoryId with all sub categories?

**Example**

Category

```
Id  ParentId  Name

1   null      One
2   null      Two
3   1         One Live 1
4   3         One Live 2
```

Documents

```
Id  CategoryId  Name

1   1         Document 1
2   2         Document 5
3   3         Document 2
4   4         Document 3
```

And I want get total document *One*. I should get total by 3

Comment: at least try, then we can help you

Comment: Sorry I have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
count = (from document in Documents
         join category in Categories 
         on document.CategoryId equals category.Id
         select document).Count();
```

Comment: This doesn't take subcategories into account.

Comment: Neither does the question? where is SubCategory in the data model? @Greg there is more than enough information here for you to go from there.

Comment: _"How I can get total documents by categoryId **with all sub categories?**"_ `ParentId` refers to the parent category. Any category with a `ParentId` is a subcategory of that parent (notice that cat 4 is a subcategory of cat 3, which in turn is a subcategory of cat 1, so there are multiple levels of subcategorization)

Comment: This is just differing interpretation, I considered a document to be a sub-category of Category, as that is in line with his data mode. At any rate, he has been supplied with some sample Linq which provides at least part of the answer.

Comment: A subcategory is not a document. It is a category, by definition of the word sub**category**.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote. I'll await to see your solution to @Greg's problem. Ending this discussion as is not productive.

Answer (score -1):

```cs
var count= (from c in this.db.categories
             join d in this.db.documents on c.id equals d.CategoryId
             select d).Count();
```

Comment: This doesn't take subcategories into account.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.